# Background Relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i would set background of my activity.

this is my layout (populate with list view)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/girone"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/away"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vs"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vs"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If i write `android:background="@drawable/logo"` (to relativeLayout), the image `logo.png` is not scale... where I'm wrong?

Comment: Questionis not clear, ask what u want actually

Comment: Can you post the screenshot here for what you want exactly?

Comment: Try changing your color to something more bright #ff0000 so you would understand how much part it is actually taking.

Comment: Where is your listview in above layout, also can not see that you have use logo.png as background.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"
     >
```

Comment: Where is the listview in above layout. I am able to see only textviews

Comment: Arvind is right... you missed the  android:layout_height="fill_parent" attribute in your parent relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_height` attribute to `RelativeLayout` xml as below...

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >
```

**Update:**

The XML layout which working perfectly...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/logo" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/girone"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/away"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vs"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vs"
        style="@style/NomeSquadra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/girone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add image with question of current layout output?

Comment: update xml as above and clean and build your project...then run it again.

Comment: MY LIST VIEW

http://i.stack.imgur.com/4SxXn.png


MY BACKGROUND

http://i.stack.imgur.com/heg3c.png

i would merge the two

Comment: in my case...its working perfectly. I'm giving you the xml of yours which working for me.

Comment: if i delete  the textview inside layout, work fine. If i add the textview (list of the results of football) not work....

Comment: my goal is to have the background and the list of TextView above

Comment: which `TextView` you are talking about?

Comment: please, give me an screenshot with textviews.

Comment: MY LIST VIEW (list of the textview) http://i.stack.imgur.com/4SxXn.png 
MY BACKGROUND http://i.stack.imgur.com/heg3c.png 
i would merge the two so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6g7Vc.png

Comment: as I understand...any how, you are setting background color to the `TextView`s.

Comment: I'm not saying entire code...post the getView() method code.

Comment: this is my getView:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
   
   
   RowWrapper wrapper;
   if (convertView == null)
   {
    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_results, null);
    wrapper = new RowWrapper(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(wrapper);
   }
   else
   {
    wrapper = (RowWrapper) convertView.getTag();
   }
   
   Risultati risultati = (Risultati) getItem(position);
   wrapper.poulate(risultati);
   
   return convertView;
  }
and then seen http://www.latanadidiablo.com/populate.txt

Comment: HAMID see here:

My activity: http://www.latanadidiablo.com/activity.java
Layout xml: http://www.latanadidiablo.com/activity_results.txt

 and i want this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6g7Vc.png

Comment: I can't see to those given link...please, give `poulate()` method code.

Comment: this link give me `Forbidden` warning.

Comment: this link also have same problem.

Comment: I'm suggesting you some thing...check them out...check in your `poulate()` method that does it contain any code which setting `Background` to those `TextView`s. if does then comment/ remove them...then run your code...I think, you will get the problem solved.

Comment: yes in my populate i make: this.girone.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

you think that's it the problem?

Comment: yeah...that's one of the problem...comment it...and find out that there has any line which have `setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)`.

Comment: i commented all setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) and setBackgroundColor(Color.RED) but it's the same.
Each textview have the logo.png as background

Answer (score 0):

add height to the parent of this layout

```
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: android:background="@drawable/logo" also set dude

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

Comment: i think there is something prob with that picture dude